# Bisect Tool Not Working

Tags: modeling, bisect

First time using Blender in years and trying to learn all of the new 2.8 goodness, but my Bisect tool seems to not be working. I select it and all it lets me do is select and move vertices. It doesn't even show the option to bisect in the shortcuts bar.
[image]

When it should look like this (Taken from a youtube tutorial)[image]

If anyone else has ran into this issue and can offer help that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I opened up Blender the next day and now the bisect tool seems to work fine. I guess I just needed to close and open Blender for the tool to fix itself. Kind of frustrating that a bug like this exists, but it was an easy solution and I can't expect a huge update like this to work perfectly. Hope this helps anyone else with similar issues!

Comment: In that case, this sounds reportable? (Having checked everywhere for duplicates, and made best efforts to consistently reproduce, in a minimal example)

Answer (score 0):

I had to select a face, edge, or some vertices first, in Edit mode, with the Bisect tool selected.

Comment: I tried that, but all it did was move whatever I had selected.

Comment: Are you able to click "off" the object to clear the selection, then click back on it while the "Select" tool is active, then switch to the "Bisect" tool?

Answer (score 0):

It works when I select the bisect from the menu>mesh>bisect. ( I'm having the same issue with the bisect tool from the toolbar in 2.83)

Comment: Restore default worked for me... some time after.